# How to manage secret rotation used by spring boot app running on ECS in AWS cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

My organization is running spring boot app on AWS ECS docker container which reads the credentials for Postgres sql from secrets manager in AWS during boot up. AS part of security complaince, we are rotating the secrets every 3 months. The spring boot app is loosing connection with the database and going down when the RDS credentials are rotated.we have to restart it in order to pick the new credentials to work properly. Is there any way I can read the credentials automatically once the credentials are rotated to avoid restarting the application manually?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that the postgres database in AWS supports passwordless authentication using IAM roles. We can generate a token which is valid for 15 mins and can connect to database using that token. I prefer this way of connecting to database rather than using password for my database. More details about setting up password less authentication can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html)

Code example as below

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.services.rds.auth.GetIamAuthTokenRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.rds.auth.RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class RdsIamAuthDataSource extends org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RdsIamAuthDataSource.class);

  private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 5432;

  private static final String USESSL = "useSSL";

  private static final String REQUIRE_SSL = "requireSSL";

  private static final String BOOLEAN_TRUE = "true";

  private static final String VERIFY_SERVER_CERTIFICATE = "verifyServerCertificate";

  private static final String THREAD_NAME = "RdsIamAuthDataSourceTokenThread";

  /**
   * Constructor for RdsIamAuthDataSource.
   * @param props {@link PoolConfiguration}
   */
  public RdsIamAuthDataSource(PoolConfiguration props) {
    this.poolProperties = props;
  }

  @Override
  public ConnectionPool createPool() throws SQLException {
    if (pool == null) {
      return createPoolImpl();
    } else {
      return pool;
    }
  }

  protected ConnectionPool createPoolImpl() throws SQLException {
    synchronized (this) {
      return pool = new RdsIamAuthConnectionPool(poolProperties);
    }
  }

  private class RdsIamAuthConnectionPool extends ConnectionPool implements Runnable {

    private RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator rdsIamAuthTokenGenerator;
    private String host;
    private String region;
    private int port;
    private String username;
    private Thread tokenThread;

    /**
     * Constructor for RdsIamAuthConnectionPool.
     * @param prop {@link PoolConfiguration}
     * @throws SQLException {@link SQLException}
     */
    public RdsIamAuthConnectionPool(PoolConfiguration prop) throws SQLException {
      super(prop);
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(PoolConfiguration prop) throws SQLException {
      try {
        final URI uri = new URI(prop.getUrl().substring(5));
        this.host = uri.getHost();
        this.port = uri.getPort();
        if (this.port < 0) {
          this.port = DEFAULT_PORT;
        }
        this.region = StringUtils.split(this.host,'.')[2];
        this.username = prop.getUsername();
        this.rdsIamAuthTokenGenerator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
                .credentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .region(this.region)
                .build();
        updatePassword(prop);
        final Properties props = prop.getDbProperties();
        props.setProperty(USESSL, BOOLEAN_TRUE);
        props.setProperty(REQUIRE_SSL, BOOLEAN_TRUE);
        props.setProperty(VERIFY_SERVER_CERTIFICATE, BOOLEAN_TRUE);
        super.init(prop);
        this.tokenThread = new Thread(this, THREAD_NAME);
        this.tokenThread.setDaemon(true);
        this.tokenThread.start();
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Database URL is not correct. Please verify", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
      }
    }

    /**
     * Refresh the token every 12 minutes.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        while (this.tokenThread != null) {
          Thread.sleep(12 * 60 * 1000);
          updatePassword(getPoolProperties());
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Background token thread interrupted", e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void close(boolean force) {
      super.close(force);
      final Thread thread = tokenThread;
      if (thread != null) {
        thread.interrupt();
      }
    }

    private void updatePassword(PoolConfiguration props) {
      final String token = rdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.getAuthToken(GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder()
              .hostname(host)
              .port(port)
              .userName(this.username)
              .build());
      LOGGER.info("Updated IAM token for connection pool");
      props.setPassword(token);
    }
  }
}
```

Supply the following DataSource as a spring bean. That's it. Now your application will automatically refresh credentials every 12 minutes

```
@Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    final PoolConfiguration props = new PoolProperties();
    props.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://myapp.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/myschema?ssl=true");
    props.setUsername("rdsadminuser");
    props.setDriverClassName("org.somedatabase.Driver");
    return new RdsIamAuthDataSource(props);
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Keerthikant , how do you pass new token to your application again. I am facing the issue , I am using Hikari pool , I am not able to pass new token after it expires in 15 mins.

Comment: @Sanjay, How are you running your application? Are you running it in local or is it running as a docker app in ECS or plain java app on EC2 ?

Comment: @Keerhikant, We are using ElaticBeanStalk.

Comment: @Sanjay: Okay. We have to extend the datasource and implement our own implementation. I have updated my answer above.